# Simpleadapter (JSON com sub-itens)

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Eu sou novato no desenvolvimento Android, e estou tentando a dias fazer minha primeira app funcionar porém sem sucesso.
Estou usando o AsyncTask para fazer a requisição e o SimpleAdapter, ele até trás os dados porém meu JSON tem sub-itens. É um JSON de comentários onde as vezes em um comentário tem as respostas desse comentário. Porém não tenho idéia se eu faço um listview dentro de um listview nem nda. Estou realmente perdido, pesquisei muito e nada.

Segue o JSON:

```
{
COMENTARIOS: [
{
    comentarios_id: "1053939",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "ludi",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "186.212.2.226",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:34:00",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "67",
    naogostei: "143",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1053943",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Andre",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "187.120.224.30",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:45:01",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "236",
    naogostei: "114",
    resp: [
    {
        comentarios_id: "1053945",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Usuário",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "187.39.180.166",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 09:51:54",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "143",
        naogostei: "219",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1053987",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Roberto, o Legítimo",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "177.6.152.156",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 11:39:52",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "82",
        naogostei: "124",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054030",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1053943",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "xumbinho",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "186.232.178.237",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 13:19:51",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "69",
        naogostei: "116",
        resp: [ ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1053964",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Celso",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "177.97.174.169",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 10:38:06",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "41",
    naogostei: "116",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054061",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Usuário",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "181.223.181.27",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 14:23:10",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "60",
    naogostei: "15",
    resp: [
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054173",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1054061",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "bob",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "92.59.121.38",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 17:19:32",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "5",
        naogostei: "106",
        resp: [ ]
    },
    {
        comentarios_id: "1054485",
        noticias_id: "284901",
        duelos_id: "0",
        respostas_id: "1054061",
        videos_id: "0",
        nome: "Usuário",
        email: "email@email.com.br",
        ip: "187.55.120.227",
        comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
        data_cadastro: "2018-04-04 10:24:56",
        status: "3",
        gostei: "0",
        naogostei: "0",
        resp: [ ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054304",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Jorge",
    email: "email@email.com.br",
    ip: "189.74.113.127",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 21:00:03",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "1",
    naogostei: "0",
    resp: [ ]
},
{
    comentarios_id: "1054382",
    noticias_id: "284901",
    duelos_id: "0",
    respostas_id: "0",
    videos_id: "0",
    nome: "Pé na cova",
    email: "email@email.com",
    ip: "168.194.160.137",
    comentario: "COMENTÁRIO",
    data_cadastro: "2018-04-03 23:45:29",
    status: "3",
    gostei: "1",
    naogostei: "0",
    resp: [ ]
}
]
}
```

No AsyncTask na função `protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)` eu faço a chamada do JSON dessa maneira:

```
    JSONArray comentarios = jsonObj.getJSONArray("COMENTARIOS");
    for (int i = 0; i < comentarios.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = comentarios.getJSONObject(i);
      String nome = c.getString("nome");
      String comentario = c.getString("comentario");

      HashMap<String, String> comentariotxt = new HashMap<>();

      comentariotxt.put("nome", nome);
      comentariotxt.put("comentario", comentario);

      JSONArray resp = c.getJSONArray("resp");
      if(resp.length() > 0){
          for (int j = 0; j < resp.length(); j++){
              JSONObject d = resp.getJSONObject(j);
              String respostaNome = d.getString("nome");
              String respostaComentario = d.getString("comentario");
              Log.d("respostaNome",respostaNome);

              HashMap<String, String> respostatxt = new HashMap<>();
              respostatxt.put("respostaNome", respostaNome);
              respostatxt.put("respostaComentario", respostaComentario);
              comentarioList.add(respostatxt);
          }
      }
      comentarioList.add(comentariotxt);
  }
```

Mas aqui já bagunça tudo. Pois eu preciso de duas coisas. Que eles tragam o comentário e as respostas em ordem e a aparência do balão de respostas vai ser diferente do balão do comentário. No momento eu estou fazendo só um listview dos comentários, mas também não sei se preciso de um outro listview pras respostas. Ou seja.. estou muito perdido! Alguém me ajuda?

Muito obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Explique mais. Não dar pra entender o que precisa

Comment: Olá Icaro! Tudo bem? A minha dúvida é que eu não sei como passo essas informações pro Layout! Pois o listview que eu fiz é somente dos comentários. Daí como faria a resposta de cada comentário ser exibido abaixo do comentário? Se eu tenho que mudar algo ou se dá pra seguir mais ou menos como eu fiz 
`- comentário
 --- resposta
 --- resposta
 --- resposta
-comentário
-comentário
 --- resposta
 --- resposta
comentário
... `

Por exemplo isso. Muito obrigado!